# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange](http://music.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to have a penetrating voice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-to-have-a-penetrating-voice)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is this part of the guitar called (see pic)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/what-is-this-part-of-the-guitar-called-see-pic)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Recognizing downwards intervals by humming corresponding upwards interval - bad practice?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/recognizing-downwards-intervals-by-humming-corresponding-upwards-interval-bad)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to be consistent in studio performance?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/how-to-be-consistent-in-studio-performance)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Understanding V/ii♭9 Chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12336/understanding-v-ii9-chord)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Any good tips on keeping pieces "on ice"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12201/any-good-tips-on-keeping-pieces-on-ice)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is It too late to start learning keyboard again?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/is-it-too-late-to-start-learning-keyboard-again)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Uses for augmented chords in composition](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/uses-for-augmented-chords-in-composition)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Two electric guitars on one amp](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12382/two-electric-guitars-on-one-amp)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Improvisation on Piano](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12409/improvisation-on-piano)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

Comment: The improvisation question is really broad and vague. Books have been written about improvisation (which seems like an oxymoron). There are many techniques to improvisation and one answer can't well answer the question. It should be broken down into specific questions.